# Slow wireless connection - HP laptop Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, connection

I am new to the Ubuntu environment, but it is very intuitive and I am usually able to find anything I need. But, as the topic states, I can't establish proper connection. I have previously installed Linux Mint, but couldn't find the way to fix the slow connection. I have tried several methods from forums, that it couldn't do. I thought that installing Ubuntu 16.04 would help, but the problem persists. Maybe you guys know how to resolve the issue. I have just performed installation of ubuntu again, so it's freshly installed system now. 
Thanks in advance!

[wireless info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23782308/)

Comment: Mint is based on Ubuntu and likely to be using the same drivers. Everything else being equal the same behavior should be expected. It's a surprise you *tried several methods* but no one told you the problem is at your router: The *2.4G-Vectra-WiFi-06B316* has the worst possible wireless encryption settings. Please change it to **WP2-AES** only. Not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode (your current setting) and certainly not TKIP (your current setting).

Comment: Thank you kind sir! I think it may help.... Unfortunately, my Internet provider has blocked my router settings, and they also can't change them (only basics, like name, password...). I phoned to them, and they've changed the encryption settings (to wpa only, I think. Guy said that he couldn't do more), and it helped a little - still slower connection than in Win.  Anyways, thank you!

Comment: I hate when that happens. If I were you I would be strongly suggesting them to change that router ASAP. Anyway, it should support WPA2 only and also anything **else** than TKIP (terminology varies, AES also appears as CCMP). You may be able able to add your own router (connect via Ethernet), enable WiFi and ask your ISP to disable their router's WiFi). A relatively cheap workaround for those bad routers many ISPs impose on their customers.